# Accessing dumped hard drive using Virtualbox

Tags: windows, hard-drive, virtualbox, partitioning

I have dumped a Windows XP partition from another computer's hard drive using `dd` over the network. Now I have the .img file, but I need further instructions if I can boot into that hard drive using Virtualbox.

I have already converted the partition into a .vdi using

```
vboxmanage convertdd file.img file.vdi
```

Note that I have no idea how .vdi files are arranged. I'm guessing this may be related to the fact that I `dd`'d the partition only and not the MBR?

Comment: If you don't have the MBR the image you created won't be bootable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The utility provided by VirtualBox obviously didn't work.
I overcame th problem by first creating a new virtual machine, and made a clean Windows XP installation. Then I mounted the newly created drive, erased the contents and copied the content from my .img file. This was the quickest solution I could think of.